# Get progressive sum of column by date

Tags: sql-server, snowflake

I've an Employee table with StartDate and EndDate as columns. How can I get a progressive sum of employees on per daily basis?

| ID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| 3 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-03-31 |

Output should be --

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 |
| 2022-02-02 | 3 |

Comment: seems like you need to unpack the dates and take a count on it

Comment: try a search on tsql cumulative totals

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server do:

```
SELECT 
    date, 
    count(*) over(order by date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

This will return what you claim is expected output.
But your question suggests, that you should need something more...

Comment: Nice but since they seem to want one row pre date in the output, you need to add `GROUP BY date` and change the `count(*)` to `sum(count(*))`

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for catching that @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question are you expecting an output as below.

```
create table #table(id int,start_date datetime,end_date datetime)

insert into #table
select 1,'2022-02-01','2022-02-28'
UNION ALL
select 2,'2022-02-01','2022-03-31'
UNION ALL
select 3,'2022-02-02','2022-03-31'


;WITH Tally (N) AS
(
    -- Tally table starting at 0
    SELECT 0 UNION ALL       
-- 8000 rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e(n)
)
SELECT DATEADD(day,n,  start_date) thedate,COUNT(id) AS total_emp
FROM #table
CROSS JOIN Tally
WHERE N <=DATEDIFF(DAY,START_DATE,end_date)
GROUP BY DATEADD(day,n,  start_date) 
ORDER BY thedate
```

Note the tally table code is being picked up from [here](https://dwaincsql.com/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql) and it will calcluate for a maximum of 8000 rows